# mysql generate sum of each columns for selected # of rows

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate-functions

Is there any easy way to get the sum of each columns for the selected number of rows.
If not a simple mysql-only query any php/perl-mysql combination would also do.

```
select sum(col-1),sum(col-2)....sum(col-N) from 4gc_1h_atch_enb where EVENT_TIME between '2014-04-15 00:00:00' and '2014-04-15 23:00:00' and ENB='310-120-401409(M)';
```

Table has 50+ columns and also i have to repeat this for multiple(30+) such tables.

Comment: Are you asking about generating the sum(col-1) ... sum(col-n) section of the query based on the individual table layout?

Comment: You may have entirely legitimate reasons for constructing a table with 50 columns, but such tables are frequently symptomatic of poor design. Likewise the number of tables.

Comment: I only see dynamic SQL as an option here - an ugly one - sorry.

Comment: @frlan I originally wanted the easy way to query,but if not i am ok with dynamic generation of sum(col-1)....query itself

Comment: @Strawberry Its actually import of huge raw log for BI tools.so really  dont have any control on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do a CONCAT with INFORMATION_SCHEMA views for Columns and Tables and then a GROUP_CONCAT with that.  A basic structure looks like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(',COLUMN_NAME,')')),',',(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = '4gc_1h_atch_enb'
AND DATA_TYPE <> 'int'))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = '4gc_1h_atch_enb'
AND DATA_TYPE = 'int'
```

That will give you the "sum(col-1),sum(col-2)....sum(col-N)" part.  You can do something similar with tables.  The WHERE part is also part of the CONCAT.  In the end you will have a script to execute.

Comment: Just curious at the end its missing the closing bracket.Per my understanding this is taken care CONCAT itself right?
`SUM(NE_ID),SUM(INIT_ATTEMPT),......,SUM(COMB_RSC_FULL),SUM(COMB_SYS
`

Comment: also is there any way i could modify this query to just include the column names alone (without SUM()) for non-integer & non--float column types?